# Adding buttons to panels on tabpages - buttons show up on wrong panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, controls

I have been using my Foci program for some time. It is controlled by a mock-ini file that defines the tabpages, the buttons and what they do when clicked. I can change everything by editing the ini file. I decided the easiest way to group the buttons on a given tabpage was by placing each button on a panel. So this morning I added the code section that is defined by 'With newPanel'. The rest of the code was already working correctly. Each panel is large enough to provide a boundary around the button which is placed in the center of the panel. The panels are sized such that they touch thereby forming an area with other buttons of the same color.

My problem is that all of the buttons on a given tabpage are being added to the first panel. Sufficient panels are appearing for all of the buttons, but they are all empty except for the first one. I am perplexed by this behavior.

Here is the relevant code:

```
        newButton = New Button
        SelectATab(sTab)            'select correct tab...

        With newButton
            .Name = "btn" & sText.Replace(" ", [String].Empty)
            .Text = sText
            .Tag = sFullPath
            .BackColor = BC
            .ForeColor = FC
            .Location = NewLocation()
            .Width = Convert.ToInt32(oIni.ButtonWidth)
            .Height = Convert.ToInt32(oIni.ButtonHeight)
        End With

        Dim newPanel As New Panel

        With newPanel
            .Name = "pnl" & sTab & sText.Replace(" ", [String].Empty)
            .Text = sText
            .Tag = sFullPath
            .BackColor = Color.Black
            .Location = NewPanelLocation(newButton.Location)
            .Width = Convert.ToInt32(oIni.ButtonWidth + 20)
            .Height = Convert.ToInt32(oIni.ButtonHeight + 10)
        End With

        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf MyEventHandler
        newPanel.Controls.Add(newButton)
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(newPanel)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the effect that I wanted. I am now adding both the buttons and the panels directly to the tabpage. Before, I was adding the button to the panel, then adding the panel to the tabpage. I guess that controls do not actually get added to panels. I was wrong in thinking that they do.

Comment: Panels *are* container controls, the buttons should go in `newPanel` controls if the panels are supposed to contain them.  The problem is in your `NewLocation()` method.  if there is one button per panel, then the button location would be the same one every one.

Comment: Thank-you, Plutonix. I can see that you are right. I will leave my code as it is, however, since it isn't important that the buttons be contained by the panels. I seek only the visual grouping effect of what are essentially tiles created by the panels. It is good to clear my understanding for future efforts.

Comment: Since they are added dynamically, you might have a hard time finding them as they wont be in the collection(s) you think they are

Comment: I don't need to find them. They just pass a fully qualified filename to Process.start which is specified in the ini file. Thanks again.